# db2 date format concat specific time

Tags: sql, date, db2, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to query data that happened between Yesterday 6 AM and Today 6 AM.

I'm having a problem in concatenation.

This is what I've tried.

```
Where update_time between date(CURRENT DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy 06:00:00')- 1 DAYS 
                      and date(CURRENT DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy 06:00:00')
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` - what happens if you have an event that comes in at _exactly_ 6AM?  As is, it'd be included in _both_  days (today, tomorrow), probably not what you want.  It's much better to use explicit ranges (lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive, or `update_time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 DAYS AND update_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`), _especially_ when dealing with timestamps.  Oh, and don't suffix columns by their type, name them so it's obvious (ie: `update_time` -> `updated_at`) - it's noise, and has the potential to go out-of-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE UPDATE_TIME 
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO) || ' 06:00:00') - 1 DAY
AND TIMESTAMP(CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO) || ' 06:00:00')
```

Updated to answer X-Zero's comment:

The DB2 function `CHAR(CURRENT DATE,ISO)` takes the current date, and converts it to a character string in the `ISO` format.  Taking today's date, the CHAR function would return "2012-09-18".

Next, we concatenate (||) a time string to the date string.  The space in the time string creates a character DB2 timestamp in the correct format.  "2012-09-18 06:00:00".

Finally, the DB2 function `TIMESTAMP` takes the character DB2 timestamp and converts it to an actual DB2 timestamp.

Comment: You don't need to (explicitly, at least) cast `CURRENT_DATE` to character, and what's up with that leading space in the time portion?  Also, you could discourage him from using `BETWEEN`...

Comment: I'm sure it does; I was just wondering why you were performing the cast, when the first thing the function does is to convert that character-date _back_ to an actual date type.  And I warned against `BETWEEN` because performing this statement on subsequent days will include any rows updated at _exactly_ 6AM multiple times - both 'today', and 'tomorrow'.